# Evaluate $\int_{{\frac {\pi}{8}}}^{{\frac {7\,\pi}{8}}}\!{\frac {\ln \left( 1- \cos \left( t \right) \right) }{\sin \left( t \right) }}\,{\rm d}t$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form, polylogarithm

I'm interested in this integral: $\int_{{\frac {\pi}{8}}}^{{\frac {7\,\pi}{8}}}\!{\frac {\ln  \left( 1- \cos \left( t \right)  \right) }{\sin \left( t \right) }}\,{\rm d}t$

I found this particular closed form with Maple and finally : $-{\frac { \left( \ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2}} \right)  \right) ^{
2}}{2}}-{\frac {{\pi}^{2}}{12}}+{\frac {11\, \left( \ln  \left( 2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{8}}-{\frac { \left( \ln  \left( 1+\sqrt {2}
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {3\, \left( \ln  \left( 2+\sqrt {2}
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{4}}+{\it {Li_2}} \left( -{\frac {\sqrt {2+
\sqrt {2}}}{4}}+{\frac{1}{2}} \right) 
$, where \Li_2 is the dilogarithm function.

Please, can someone prove it ?

Comment: Start with the property of definite integrals that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int{\frac {\log \left( 1- \cos \left( t \right) \right) }{\sin \left( t \right) }}\,dt=\int \sin(t){\frac {\log \left( 1- \cos \left( t \right) \right) }{1-\cos^2\left( t \right) }}\,dt$$

Let
$$x=\cos(t)\implies I=\int \frac{\log(1-x)}{x^2-1} \,dx=-\frac12\int\frac{\log(1-x)}{ 1-x}\,dx-\frac12\int\frac{\log(1-x)}{ x+1}\,dx$$

$$\int\frac{\log(1-x)}{ 1-x}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(1-x)$$
For the second integral, integration by parts gives
$$\int\frac{\log(1-x)}{x+1}\,dx=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)+\log (1-x) \log \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)$$ Combining the results

$$I=\int \frac{\log(1-x)}{x^2-1} \,dx=\frac{1}{4} \left(\log (1-x) (\log (4(1-x))-2 \log (x+1))-2
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)\right)$$ Go back to $t$ if you wish and use bounds.

Comment: So great and thanks !

Comment: @Dens. Glad to help ! In fact the problem is simple if you think about the first trick $$\frac 1 {\sin(x)}=\frac {\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\frac {\sin(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}$$

Comment: Merci bien pour le conseil !

Comment: If I may ask, where are you located ? I am in Pau. Cheers :-)

Comment: Je suis francais et je me trouve en Saône et Loire.D'ailleurs, je vous avais écris au sujet d'une publication sur Vixra << values of barnes function >>. C'est moi !

Comment: @Dens. NIce to see you again ! Sorry for not remembering (age problem !!!). Cheers :-)